# Mysqli->commit always commits even though there is an error in a statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to use commit() to check if there is an error in some query. Although there is an error in one statement, it continues working.

Here is an example of my code,

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$stmt_a = "INSERT INTO choice(title, question_id) VALUES('choice_A', 2)";
$stmt_b = "INSERT INTO choice(title, question_id) VALUES('choice_B', 2)";
$stmt_c = "INSERT INTO choice(title, question_id) VALUES('choice_C')";

$mysqli->query($stmt_a);    
$mysqli->query($stmt_b);        
$mysqli->query($stmt_c);    

if(!$mysql->commit()){
  echo "MySQL commit failed !";
}else{
  echo "successful!"
}
```

Based on the code, although stmt_c is missing a question_id value, it **committed the stmt_a and stmt_b with ignoring stmt_c**. Besides, the result will be at else condition which is successful.

Did I go to the wrong way to check the result of commit() ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @PetSerAl Very sorry for my clumsy. I've added it.

Comment: You should check result of each query, rather then checking result of commit only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a query throws an error, don't discard the return value.  [`mysqli->query()` returns false on error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).  You should never be calling it without checking its return value.

The point of `COMMIT` is to commit whatever changes you *did* make into the database and release any row locks you still hold.  If you caused errors during the transaction, the server assumes you must have corrected your problem, and must be satisfied with the final result... otherwise you wouldn't be trying to commit.

`COMMIT` is only supposed to fail if whatever changes you made can't actually be committed -- so failing at commit time is rare, usually only occurring if something catastrophic happens, like the database server crashing or being restarted while your transaction is in progress. (Of course, it can happen for additional reasons if you are running Galera Replication Provider, but if you were, you would know it.)

If your prior queries caused errors, or didn't actually insert/update/delete anything, that is not supposed to make a commit fail... by design.